# GameKit: What is the connection type when using GKSession without GKPeerPickerController

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, wifi, gamekit

I am implementing a `BlueTooth` and `Wifi` Based chat program for `iPhone`. For connection purpose I am using `GameKit`. But because of some special requirements application I can't use the default `GKPeerPickerController`. So I instead I created a `GKSession` and `GKSessionDelegate` combo to detect the peers. After they find each other, they can chat.

Now I have tested the chat functionality on three `mac-minis` using `simulator`, one simulator and one `iPod`, one `iPhone` and one `Simulator`. I am able to chat in all of the above scenarios. But some how the `iPhone` and `iPod` won't detect each other.

Also I am curious about type of connection is happening between all these devices. Because theoretically `GameKit` supports both, `BlueTooth` and `WiFi`. Now the problem is that `GKPeerPickerController` let's one choose specifically between `BlueTooth` and `WiFi`, (unfortunately the implementation of `WiFi` is not documented anywhere.) This is fine, but what about the custom scenario when one implements his or her own `GKSession` and `GKSessionDelegate` Combo. When one creates `GKSession` Object using the only `init` method available:

```
– initWithSessionID:displayName:sessionMode:
```

only configuration option this provides is `sessionMode` but it has only three options

```
   GKSessionModeServer,
   GKSessionModeClient,
   GKSessionModePeer,
```

None of which indicates connection choice between `Bluetooth` and `WiFi`.

But I have disabled `bluetooth` on the `iPod` and tested it with a `mac-mini` it works so I guess this is using `WiFi`. Also in the log I get following line:

```
DNSServiceRegister callback: Ref=4c3f3d0, Flags=2, ErrorType=0 name=00XGT0H0A..BTChat1 regtype=_0eilkgh5o2mq17._udp. domain=local.
```

The `DNSServiceRegister` and `udp` part make me think the communication is happening over `TCP/IP`.

So does this mean that when I start with `GKSession` and `GKSessionDelegate` the default method of communication is WiFi only, or does it support `WiFi` and `bluetooth` both at the same time (though I never got a single indication that `BlueTooth` connection was happening).

But `GameKit` is supposed to be mainly about `BlueTooth` Right? Can anybody   put light on the situation about what exactly is happening?

Also have you seen any sample code where somebody has implemented  WiFi interface for  `GKPeerPickerController`?

---

**Solved:**

OK Found it myself. `GKSession` and `GKSessionDelegate` custom implementations as I have mentioned in the question works for both `bluetooth` and `WiFi`. Actually the `iPhone (JailBroked)` I am using had some issues with `BlueTooth` and possibly that was preventing `Gamekit` to Work Properly, After hard resetting the phone and turning `Airplane` mode on off , `bluetooth` on off  a few times got the `bluetooth` working on the phone. Now the app is working fine in both `WiFi` and `BlueTooth` mode.

Comment: Hi Pritam, that's to say, there is no way to set which way(bluetooth or wifi) to communicate with, right?

Comment: @Dio yes, at least that was how it was when I coded that piece, but it has been long time since then and I haven't kept up with GameKit.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know if GKPeerPicker behaves in similar way? I mean if selecting NEAR mode allows you to connect over wifi/bluetooth ?

I suspect INTERNET mode is for connecting to remote servers using TCP/IP.
Regards